# gtk_widget_set_realized was not declared in this scope

Tags: linux, gtk, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile `OpenCV 3.1.0` on `RHEL 6.4` and getting the following error:

```
[ 34%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_gtk.cpp.o
/hpcf/libs/opencv/vendor/3.1.0-2/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp: In function ‘void cvImageWidget_realize(GtkWidget*)’:
/hpcf/libs/opencv/vendor/3.1.0-2/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:167: error: ‘gtk_widget_set_realized’ was not declared in this scope
/hpcf/libs/opencv/vendor/3.1.0-2/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp: In function ‘void cvImageWidget_size_allocate(GtkWidget*, GtkAllocation*)’:
/hpcf/libs/opencv/vendor/3.1.0-2/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:379: error: ‘gtk_widget_get_realized’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_gtk.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

We clearly have `gtk` as it shows in `cmake`:

```
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.18.9)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.22.5)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
```

So I'm not sure how to fix this problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, so if it helps:

I had the same error when I was compiling OpenCV 3.1.0 on RHEL. 
I looked up the code in highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp from OpenCV 2.4.3 branch. 
Do the following:

- Replace "gtk_widget_set_realized" with "GTK_WIDGET_SET_FLAGS"
- Replace "gtk_widget_get_realized" with "GTK_WIDGET_REALIZED"

Once I changed these, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest version of gcc

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
>   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9`